construction of ということ
I noticed one nuance in the construction ということ.　On JLPT sensei there are 2 ways of constructions of  ということ and i want to clarify some moments.
So, grammar that implies that I want to give a phrase a definition/explanation or I'm talking about conclusions, I don't need to put "だ" between the phrase and the ということは -   just Clause 1    ということは  clause 2. - looks like a  fixed expression

30％割引きということは、２万円なら６千円安くなるんですね。

But when I just want to turn phrase into a noun, I need to put だ between the noun, なadjective and ということ?

あなたが私の声が好きだということがとても嬉しいです。
私は今日が結婚記念日だということを忘れていました。

So, this is the difference in the article i read.
As a result, when I want to draw a conclusion from a phrase, or give an explanation for a phrase, there is no need in だ？　Clause 1   ということは  clause 2 only. But when i want to turn phrase into a noun i need to put だ, Noun + だ / な-adjective + だ + ということ.
Did I understand these nuances correctly?
P.S: by the way, going back to the grammar of "ということは" by which we give a definition/explanation, if I want to put "ということだ" or "ことだ" at the end of a sentence, should I put だ　 between the noun/なadjective and ということだ/ことだ? It seems like it can be omitted, but I'm not sure about this.
